# How to acces my application database file in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I create a application that use SQLite database and insert some data and then I need this full sqlite database file and i try to acces it but I didnot found database file, How to acces this file for use my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Emulator then you can access your database, just by pulling it out from **File Manager** from following path: `data/data/com.my.package/databases/mydb.sqlite`

If you are running your application on your device then use following code to get database from your above filePath (since you cannot access internal file system of android device)

```
try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "/data/com.yourApp.common/databases/yourApp.db";
                String backupDBPath = "/yourApp.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

After that, once you have your db file, you can view it from Mozilla add On (Plugin) called SQLte Manager. Use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ to download it.

Comment: you don't need to root your device, just write above code somewhere in your app, and view your database.

Comment: how to this line "sd.canWrite()" is true?

Comment: It will only work if you have provided permission in manifest file as "EXTERNAL_STORAGE" as you are going to store your db file on SD card.